# How to backup contacts without a Microsoft Account?

Tags: contacts, transfer

I have a windows phone on which I have a locked up MS Account. I need to restore the phone but first I need to save all the contacts - how can I export the contacts to another device without having the MS Account active?

Comment: What do you mean the MS account is "locked up"? Can you log in to https://people.live.com and export your contacts from there?

Comment: Why don't you just try to unlock the account? Seems the easy way to me.

Comment: someone has tampered with the phone and MS Account details are not valid ones i have the details for. When I try to unlock, I cannot answer the security questions unfortunatley

Comment: If you know who messed up the settings, you could get them to un-mess-them-up.

Answer (score 0):

The best method is to unlock your MS account by following the method shown in this link

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows/outlook/account-temporarily-blocked

Or just [GoogleIt](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how%20to%20unlock%20microsoft%20account&oq=how%20to%20unblock%20microsoft%20ac&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.14013j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)--- [BingIt](http://www.bing.com/search?q=how%20to%20unlock%20microsoft%20account&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=how%20to%20unlock%20microsoft%20account&sc=2-31&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=f7016ae033d444d7bcaef31c28314266)

Or just use a contact manager app available on the apps store to backup your contacts. for example i use Rap dialer. It has a backup/restore feature (It uses Onedrive- you could make a new account) you could also try out other apps

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it. When you log in again with the same Microsoft Account all contacts will return

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Transfer my Data](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/transfer-my-data/9wzdncrfj3dr) app from Microsoft. It can directly transfer contacts from one phone to an another. Or else you can export contacts to SD card and import them in another phone.